# What is the formula for beta weighted delta and gamma?

Tags: options, beta, delta, gamma

I am trying to calculate the beta weighted delta and gamma for a portfolio of options of different underlying stocks, but I can't seem to find the correct formula.

Can someone point me to it or a book that contains it?

Comment: What is beta weighted? Is it under Black Scholes model?

Comment: By beta weighting I mean, using the beta of the underlying stock to use with the individual options that make up a portoflio to come up with a delta of entire portfolio.

Answer (score 4):

I've started thinking about this, too. My gedanken conclusion turned out to be too simple once I found what I was after: http://www.investment-and-finance.net/derivatives/o/option-beta.html, which I've confirmed in [Black & Scholes (1973)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos323/papers/black_scholes73.pdf) p10 (eq 15).

In short:
$$
\beta_{\text{option}} = \frac{S\cdot\Delta}{O}{\beta_S}
$$
where $S$ is the underlying price ($x$ in the B&S paper), $O$ is the option price ($w_1$ in B&S), $\Delta$ is the usual $\partial{O}/\partial{S}$, and $\beta_S$ is $\beta$ for the underlying.

Regarding your question, you'd just have to re-arrange this to use an empirically measured option $\beta$, and differentiate for Gamma. I'm not sure that gets you where you want to go, though.