# Correct beta weighted delta options formula?

Tags: options, portfolio-management, option-strategies, delta-hedging

Is this the correct formula for beta weighted delta: http://www.nishatrades.com/blog/beta-weighted-delta

[image]

I've seen this [What is the formula for beta weighted delta and gamma?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15131/what-is-the-formula-for-beta-weighted-delta-and-gamma/44045#44045) but they seem to be doing something completely different. Beta weighted delta doesn't involve Black Scholes.

For the above, they have a delta of 30, which means .30. Why is it necessary to multiply the delta by 100?

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't multiplying the delta by 100 just translate each option contract to the equivalent stock shares, which is needed for beta weighting?